# TypeError: assertEqual() missing 1 required positional argument: 'second'

Tags: python-unittest, testcase

I am working on a project in Runestone using test.testEqual().  I work with a Anaconda/Spyder console and translate code back into Runestone.  Python doesn't seem to support test.testEqual so I have attempted to use TestCase.assertEqual(first,second, msg) method under the unittest framework.  My code throws the error message:
TypeError: assertEqual() missing 1 required positional argument: 'second'

but as I show in the code below I include both arguments in the call. I am new to unit testing so not sure where to go in order to solve this issue?

switched from test.testEqual() to TestCase.assertEqual(first,second,msg)

```
from unittest import TestCase
def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    dsquared = dx**2 + dy**2
    result = dsquared**0.5
    return result

TestCase.assertEqual(distance(1,2, 1,2),0,msg='Equal')
TestCase.assertEqual(distance(1,2, 4,6), 5, msg='Equal')
TestCase.assertEqual(distance(0,0, 1,1), 2**0.5, msg='Equal')
```

We would expect the three test cases to Pass based on their execution in Runestone consoles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using TestCase in a different way. Instead make a test class and inherit unittest.TestCase. Add an individual test then you are good to go

```
class TestDistance(TestCase):

    def test_distance(self):
        self.assertEqual(distance(1, 2, 1, 2), 0, msg='Equal')
        self.assertEqual(distance(1, 2, 4, 6), 5, msg='Equal')
        self.assertEqual(distance(0, 0, 1, 1), 2 ** 0.5, msg='Equal')
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and guidance! I will go back and implement this.

Answer (score 4):

The [approach from w33b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362354/typeerror-assertequal-missing-1-required-positional-argument-second/56676848#56676848) works just fine but, for the sake of getting your approach working (since you are very close), you actually just need to instantiate the `TestCase` class.

The way you've written it, you are only referencing the class; but, in order to use its methods, the class needs to be instantiated with the `()`.

```
    TestCase().assertEqual(distance(1,2, 1,2),0,msg='Equal')
    TestCase().assertEqual(distance(1,2, 4,6), 5, msg='Equal')
    TestCase().assertEqual(distance(0,0, 1,1), 2**0.5, msg='Equal')
```